# How to improve my code of chat room in C++?

Tags: c++

In my code of chat room. I use "while(true)" to keep receive message, this way waste my CPU.How can I improve my code? Now I have no idea about it.

(This is a part of my code)

```
void* CooloiClientSocket::Recv_t(void* arg)
{
    std::string message;
    CooloiSocket* serverSocket = static_cast<CooloiSocket*>(arg);
    //CooloiClientSocket *p = new CooloiClientSocket;
    while(true)
    {
        if(Recv(*serverSocket,message))
        {

            std::cout << message << std::endl;
        }
        else
            break;

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Use some asynchronous IO model.

Comment: Replace `sleep(1)` with `sleep(500)` if you do not want to write a more sophisticated IO model.

Comment: You should look for a synchronous recv function, or some notification of available data (e.g. `select()`, `poll()`)... without telling us what socket library you're using, hard for us to provide more specific advice.